# How to bind a value to a variable using ng-init in a ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a project based on angular. I am facing a problem while initialising a variable in ng-repeat.I want to initialise a variable in ng-init and use it in ng-model.I am getting following error in console. any help will be appreciated

```
ionic.bundle.js:25510 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid  key at column 6 of the expression [key={{component.name}}] starting at [{component.name}}].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=6&p3=key%3D%7B%7Bcomponent.name%7D%7D&p4=%7Bcomponent.name%7D%7D
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13248:12
at Object.AST.throwError (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26061:11)
at Object.AST.object (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26048:16)
at Object.AST.primary (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25956:22)
at Object.AST.unary (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25944:19)
at Object.AST.multiplicative (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25931:21)
at Object.AST.additive (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25922:21)
at Object.AST.relational (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25913:21)
at Object.AST.equality (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25904:21)
at Object.AST.logicalAND (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25896:21)
at Object.AST.logicalOR (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25888:21)
at Object.AST.ternary (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25874:21) <div ng-repeat="component in reportTemplate" ng-init="key={{component.name}}" class="inputFieldSection inputFieldTitle" ng-if="component.type == 'text'" data-ng-animate="1">
```

following is my code snippet

```
<div ng-repeat="component in reportTemplate" ng-init="key={{component.name}}" class="inputFieldSection inputFieldTitle" ng-if="component.type == 'text'">
                          <label class="item item-input">
                            <input type="text" name={{component.name}}  ng-model=reportTemplateKeyData[key] ng-focus="clearValidation();" max-length="50" required placeholder="{{component.label}}">
                          </label>
                          <p ng-show="createReportForm[component.name].$error.required">Please Enter {{component.name}}</p>
                   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove {{}}.

```
ng-init="key=component.name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the ng-init to: `ng-init="key=component.name"`